# Drupal: a block with only some external javascript

Tags: drupal

Id like to add a block to my homepage that contains some javascript, more specifically the code provided by del.icio.us to output a tagroll.

its actually just a link to an external file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/js/tags/dude123?title=del.icio.us-cloud&count=7&sort=freq&flow=cloud&color=666666-999999&size=12-35"></script>
```

if i just paste this in the "block content" field, obviously nothing is output. would the standard way be to create the block programatically and then use drupal_add_js ?

Comment: @quickcel answer is the way to go. note that you cannot add external javascripts with drupal_add_js in drupal6 (this can be done in d7 though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can paste the script tags directly into the block content field and it will work.  You just need to make sure that whatever input filter you are using doesn't strip out the script tags.